# Nginx Configuration Issue - Blank Page and MIME Type Error for React App with Trailing Slash or Query Parameters

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm facing an issue with my Nginx configuration when serving my vite React app using Docker containers. The app works fine for URLs without a trailing slash or query parameters, but when a trailing slash is added or query parameters are included, a blank page is displayed with the following error in the browser console:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I've noticed that the issue seems to be related to how Nginx handles the URL paths when a trailing slash or query parameters are added. For example, a URL like http://localhost/checkout/ or http://localhost/checkout/?canceled=true causes Nginx to look for assets in the wrong directory, resulting in the MIME type error. But http://localhost/checkout works just fine and displays the page correctly.
How can I configure Nginx to handle URLs with trailing slashes and query parameters correctly while serving my React app? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

My Nginx configuration is as follows:

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        alias /etc/nginx/html/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: gunicorn api.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - client_build:/react/dist
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - client_build:/etc/nginx/html/
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
volumes:
  client_build:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the logs, it seems like the problem was whenever a slash was added at the end, nginx would look for asset/static files relative to the url path. For example, if the url was http://localhost/checkout/, nginx looked for the css and js file in the /etc/nginx/html/checkout/assets/ folder instead of /etc/nginx/html/assets/.

Not sure why this doesn't happen when there is no trailing slash, but adding this in server block fixed it for me:

```
location ~ ^/.*/assets/(.*) {
    alias /etc/nginx/html/assets/$1;
}
```

This forces nginx to look for assets files directly in the assets folder.